# Elasticsearch 2.x sort with missing value treated as 0.0

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

According to mapping the field I'm sorting on is of type double
I was expecting the sort to treat missing values as 0 since I have some negative values which I expect to go below missing ones. (Currently  missing goes below negative)

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to describe that missing, or `null` values should be handled as 0 values. If you do not need to be able to distinguish them from actual '0' values, you can use a `null_value`, see [the manual](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/null-value.html)

If you do, in another situation, have to distinguish them, you might need to add a flag or something (so a second field) to actually say "but this was actually missing", but that's really depending on your usecase

a quick example:

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "status_code": {
          "type":       "integer",
          "null_value": 0 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT test/my_type/1
{
  "status_code": null
}
PUT test/my_type/2
{
  "status_code": -1
}
PUT test/my_type/3
{
  "status_code": 1
}

GET test/my_type/_search
{
    sort" : [
        { "status_code" : "desc" },
    ]
}
```

This will return the documents in order `2, 1, 3` as expected

Answer (score 1):

There is `exists` query (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html), which you can use along with `not` filter in `function score` query (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) for sorting, and give needed boost/score for missing values as 0.0 in your case.

But I suggest much simpler solution - just index your documents with that field equals 0.0 instead of missing value and it will make things much easier - you will be able just sort on the needed field.